# associating Ellipse2D with JTable cells

Tags: java, swing

Currently I have written some code that selects a cell in a JTable when the user clicks on an Ellipse2D.  I also want to .fill the Ellipse2D if a user clicks on the associated cell in the JTable.  With the code below, how would I do this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SelfContainedExample extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private Map<Ellipse2D.Double, Point> shapesMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Ellipse2D.Double[] ellipses = new Ellipse2D.Double[] {
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 100, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(175, 100, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 100, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 160, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(175, 160, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 160, 30, 30)};

    static Object[][] data = {{"1_1", "1_2", "1_3"},
                              {"2_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"3_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"4_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"5_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"6_1", "2_2", "2_3"}};

    static Object[] columnNames = {"1", "2", "3"};
    static JTable jtable = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    public SelfContainedExample() {

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        for (Ellipse2D.Double ellipse : ellipses) {

            shapesMap.put(ellipse, new Point(row, column));
            row++;
        }

        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            g2d.draw(ellipse);
        }

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtable);

        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(385, 119));

        tablePanel.add(jScrollPane);
        tablePanel.setSize(200, 200);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new SelfContainedExample(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        for (Ellipse2D.Double ellipse : ellipses) {
            if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                jtable.requestFocusInWindow();
                Point p = shapesMap.get(ellipse);
                jtable.editCellAt(p.x, p.y);
            }

            if (jtable.contains(e.getPoint())) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many times have you asked this question on this site?

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels this one is a first, I have asked several others related though.  I am still learning.

Comment: My concern is that your code does not show your attempt to solve this. In the future, you're going to want to show us this, else you may not be exercising your brain to its fullest, and we'll not know what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Create an Ellipse2D variable, selectedEllipse, set == to null.
- In your paintComponent, if selectedEllipse is not null, fill it.
- Listen to the JTable for selection events, this could be in your MouseListener where you get the selected row and column, and then use this information to set the selectedEllipse. You could use a Map to associate a table cell with an Ellipse, or better still, use the selected table row and column indices.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of cell selection event

Comment: @feltersnach: Simply using the MouseListener should be enough. Just make sure that an actual row and column have been selected.